# How to make the title of the page becomes in footnote automatically in latex

Tags: header-footer

[image: Similar to this]I am writing my thesis and there is a specific template required by my uni. The template requires adding the title of each chapter as a footnote. How can I do that automatically in latex?

Any help, please?

Comment: Which documentclass are you using?

Comment: The `fancyhdr` package could be helpful if you use a standard latex class.

Comment: @samcarter, I do not know how to use it. any help, please?

Comment: You probably mean adding the chapter title in the footer?

Comment: @Bernard yes. That is.

Comment: Perhaps, `titleps` is simpler to use.

Comment: @Alice Have a look at the documentation http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf There are example. The article class does not have chapters...

Comment: @samcarter, sorry, report.

Comment: Also note that \chaptermark should contain the chapter name, and there is a difference between a footnote (inside the text area) and a footer (below the text area).